# Is it worth it to compete with a big competitor starting from scratch?

Tags: seo

I'd like to know if you think it'd be worth it to compete with a relatively big competitor (160k backlinks from 2.4k domains, citation flow 47, trust flow 43, class C IPs 1.2k) whose niche is however something I have sufficient knowledge of (how-tos and technology) starting from scratch.

I am particularly interested because such domain exploits a niche language I have good fluency of and of course technology is one of the big players on search engine searches and affiliate sales.

Until now I have managed a very small niche domain in my spare time (genre-specific music), which however being so specific, couldn't but have a modest amount of visitors even if ranking high on Google.

On the other hand, it's been years I have been closely watching that domain I'd like to compete with (it has around 8k how-tos with good SEO but average or below average error-ridden or outdated content taken from various unquoted sorces, something I'd easily create myself in a few months worth of work, or even sooner with the help of a few collaborators, that domain itself is run by just a couple of people) and consistently ranks its how-tos and comparison on top positions in its niche, yielding most of its revenue in header bidding.

The template they use is nothing overly complicated, it just has the main optimizations one would use to decrease load time and not trigger Google with too many banners.

The main doubts I have is if such a domain, having larger economic resources than me, could eventually sink mine (with techniques like giving me plenty of spammy backlinks or something like that) once it finds out I am competing and getting closer than they'd like, or since their texts are already quite good SEO, their strongest assurance could be that I'd have to sacrifice too many keywords in order to create my content without having my reworkings seem close enough to theirs to allow a lawsuit?

Thank you

Frank